# How to get all data from one child in Firebase using Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: My Database]

How can I get the child email value for all items in the database without knowing the user ID?

I have tried this:

```
var userRef = Firebase(url:MY_FIREBASE_URL)
    userRef.child("email").observeSingleEventOfType(
       .Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in

            for child in snapshot.children {

                let childSnapshot = snapshot.childSnapshotForPath(child.key)
                let someValue = childSnapshot.value!["key"] as! String
                print("value \(someValue)")
            }
    })
```

and many other variations and nothing seems to work. It seems like XCode just skips the code all together.

Comment: I'm looking for a list of all e-mail addresses

Answer (score 0):

By using observeEvenType method, u can get all the "email" value without knowing user's ID

```
 databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
 let userRef = self.databaseRef.child("users")
 userRef.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: {(snapshot) in
 let email = snapshot.value?["email"] as! String
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want his to happen when I press a button. When I enter this code the code never runs. It is like the code is being skipped how to I make this code execute?

Answer (score 0):

You have read complete Tree to get all Data than you can refine the Keys and values.

```
ref.child("users").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot.key)
        print(snapshot.value)
    }
```

This will read complete tree for you at once.